# I am new to python and This is the TypeError:'<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'module'

Tags: python, django, typeerror

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("Date published!!!")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):

        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you print every variable used for storing date and check if everything is in same date format

Comment: Please explain more , because I am new to django